# UITableView load local HTML

Tags: html, ios, uitableview

I build simple app. I created UITableView and DetailViewController. I created in headers

```
DetailViewController int *webNumber and UIWebView *webName

DetailViewController.m

switch (webNumber)
{
    case 0:
}
```

How I load the local HTML?

(I write this topic from my iPhone sorry for code)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my-local-html-file" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webName loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

[more info about loadHTMLString:baseURL in Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[self.webName loadHTMLString:yourHTMLString baseURL:nil];
```

for local HTML. If you want to load an URL, change `baseURL:`